# Correcting cylinder distortion from a single point outside the cylinder.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am attempting to correct for cylinder distortion with a galvo laser. Mathwise, this is a single point where the laser's mirror is located. A certain distance `d` away from the surface with radius `r`. This object is intended to be engraved as if it were flat, while still being rounded. Typically this can be done by having a machine actually rotating the object and firing the laser straight down. However, over small areas (certainly less than a half-way) it's possible to correct for for the distortion of the surface.

[image: cylinder distortion]

The goal is to engrave the surface as if that surface was flat while the surface is a cylinder.

Couple notes. The coordinate system used is basically a linear flat rectangle. Firing the laser at +1000 is typically half way along the flat surface compared to firing the laser at +2000. Effectively that flat surface is being sort of projected on to a cylinder and the question is what is the needed transformation.

Practical examples:
https://youtu.be/OnXkxMpIgaI?si=6oThnWHjc2Z7I3zW&t=66
https://docs.lightburnsoftware.com/galvo/CylinderCorrection.html#theory

I don't know whether there's an easy method to simply project the location from the cylinder to the flat surface, or whether given the originating position is effectively a single point means that it would be best to do, in effect, collision detection. There's also open questions as to how this differs with a convex shape, and whether this is axis independent. For example, if I apply the projection for the x-axis with one radius can I do the same thing for a y-axis with a different radius (giving a different overall shape to undistort)?

Comment: So your input is a coordinate on the cylinder surface? A distance along the circumference and a vertical?

Comment: The coordinates are x/y fairly linear on the flat surface, except there's a cylinder there. And the goal is to make the make the cylinder seem like it was done as a flat rolling surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not immediately obvious what input/output is best for you, or what coordinate system to use, so I will guess what is most sensible and you may have to flip/reverse/adjust as appropriate.

Imagine I have a cylindrical, radius $r$, mug of tea sitting on my desk, oriented so the tea stays inside. My eyeball is the laser and I am looking straight at the centre of the drawing surface, distance $d$ away, which we will call $(0, 0)$. Positive $x$ is to the right, positive $y$ is up to the ceiling, and $z$ is along the laser beam but we don't care about it.

I want to draw a rectangular logo (with my laser-eyeball) centred on $(0, 0)$, which, if removed from the mug and flattened, would be $2a$ wide and $2b$ high. So we want to know which $x$ and $y$ to aim for on the imaginary flat piece of paper, tangent to the mug, to achieve this.

I don't think your red triangle is useful, since it is basically the opposite of what you want to do, so ignore it. The arc of the circle, enclosed by your blue triangle, has length $a$, meaning that it subtends the angle $\frac a r$ in the centre of the circle. The base of your blue triangle is trivially $r \sin{\frac a r}$ and the height is $d + r - r \cos{\frac a r}$. From similar triangles we can therefore see that

$$
\frac x d = \frac {r \sin{\frac a r}} {d + r - r \cos{\frac a r}}
$$

and we can express which horizontal position $x$ to aim at for a given $a$ as

$$
x = \frac {\sin{\frac a r}} {\frac d r + 1 - \cos{\frac a r}} d
$$

The hypotenuse of your blue triangle is obviously

$$
\sqrt{\left(d + r - r \cos{\frac a r}\right) ^ 2 + \left(r \sin{\frac a r}\right) ^ 2}
$$

and the hypotenuse of the smaller one chopped off by the imaginary flat paper is

$$
\sqrt{d ^ 2 + x ^ 2}
$$

where $x$ is the function of $a$ above. Again, by similar triangles, we can see that

$$
\frac y {\sqrt{d ^ 2 + x ^ 2}} = \frac b {\sqrt{\left(d + r - r \cos{\frac a r}\right) ^ 2 + \left(r \sin{\frac a r}\right) ^ 2}}
$$

and, by substituting $x$ and doing a lot of simplification, we can express which vertical position $y$ to aim at for a given $a$ and $b$ as

$$
y = \frac b {1 + \frac r d \left(1 - \cos{\frac a r}\right)}
$$

I'm not sure if this answers the last part of your question but it may be worth noting that both $x$ and $y$ depend on $a$ in an interesting way, but the relationship of $y$ to $b$ is simply linear.